# Problems calling a web service from another web service with netbeans and jax-ws

Tags: web-services, netbeans, glassfish, jax-ws

I want to expose a web service on one node that defers onto the same web service contract on another node, basically then, proxy the web service, both nodes running glassfish.

I am using netbeans and jax-ws and I cannot get it to work. I generate the web service server part and the web service client part and use the same dto's. So the service method is very simple, just passes the request on.

My current problem is that it is insiting on using ws-coordination to "coordinate" and this uses ssl to connect between the servers and I haven't configured this so it fails.

using Glassfish 2.1 and netbeans 6.7

Has anyone successfully done this? Does anyone know how to disable ws-coordination? I'd rather not use ws-coordination as I definitely don't need it and don't want to have to configure ssl.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using  [(AsyncProvider)](https://metro.dev.java.net/1.4/docs/asyncprovider.html)-based Web services.

However, you might need to write your own [TubelineAssembler](https://jax-ws-architecture-document.dev.java.net/nonav/doc21/com/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/TubelineAssembler.html) to create a tubeline without the [Tube](https://jax-ws-architecture-document.dev.java.net/nonav/doc21/com/sun/xml/ws/api/pipe/Tube.html) that processes the ws-coordination related elements. An example of how to create your own TubelineAssembler can be found [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jitu/archive/2007/02/tubes_in_jaxws_1.html).

Comment: So I can't do it with regular synchronous web services?
And going so far as using tubes to remove the impact of ws-coordination, it should be easier than that.